# How do I make web.config apply to the root folder only?

Tags: iis-7

Is there a way of preventing inheritance of the web.config file in the root of wwwroot within IIS7 to all other sub-folders?

A developer installed a web app which put files in the wwwroot folder.  All worked fine until Exchange 2010 was installed and didn't work.  Removing the web.config file in the root of wwwroot gets Exchange working (OWA etc) but breaks the web app.  Putting the web.config file back fixes the web app but breaks Exchange again.

Comment: Could you show the (approximate) folder structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent inherited configuration to child applications, you wrap the `<system.web>` tag in a `<location>` tag, with `inheritInChildApplications="false"`.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.web>
      ...
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I shouted at the web app developer and he ended up moving his junk into a new virtual directory in the end, along with its web.config file.  I did stumble on the <location> tag but wasn't aware of the inheritInChildApplications bit so thanks for pointing that out.